# Problem with base case for transfinite induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I need to prove this using transfinite induction

Let $\alpha, \beta , \gamma $ ordinals

If $\beta <\gamma$ then $\alpha + \beta < \alpha + \gamma$

I am trying to prove the statement by transfinite induction on $\gamma$

for base case $\gamma =0$,  I assume that $\beta <0$, but as there is no $\beta<0$ then $\alpha +\beta < \alpha +0$ holds for all $\beta$ ? is that correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the base case is correct.

Comment: but what if I try to prove that $\alpha + \beta > \alpha + \gamma $ (something that is false), would no be the same argument correct for the base case $\gamma =0$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying,but here are some possibly relevant observations. It obviously is false that $\forall \alpha, \beta,\gamma(\alpha+\gamma<\alpha+\beta)$. It is also false that $\forall \alpha,\beta(\alpha+0<\alpha+\beta)$. But it is not false that $\forall \alpha,\beta(\beta <0\to \alpha+0<\alpha+\beta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the base case to be $\gamma=0$ (instead of the more common $\beta=0$), you basically shift the problem to the *induction* step.

To see this, suppose you have shown the inequality for $\gamma_0$, and you want to show it for $\gamma_0+1$. Now $\beta<\gamma_0+1$. You want to use the induction hypothesis, but now we only know $\beta\le\gamma_0$, which means either $\beta<\gamma_0$ or $\beta=\gamma_0$. The first case is handled by the induciton hypothesis, but the second is not, and you have to check it manually. Now $\gamma=\gamma_0+1$, so the inequality you want to check is $\alpha+\beta<\alpha+\gamma_0+1$. This is true because $\beta=\gamma_0$. However, if you reverse the inequality to be shown, then it is false in this special case that is not reduced to the induction hypothesis.

P.S. If you're not entirely comfortable with ordinals (as I am), just substitute natural numbers for them. They are surprisingly similar (to some extent).